# Ocaml Pattern matching not doing as I expect

Tags: list, pattern-matching, ocaml

I'm having a little trouble with my OCaml program:

```
let moveRight ls i =  
  match getn ls (i+1) with
  |O -> replacex (replacex ls i O) (i+1) R
  |_ -> replacex (replacex ls i O) (i+2) R;
```

Replacex works, and replaces the i'th element in list ls with x.

But my program above doesn't.
It is supposed to do the following:
If a list is `[R; L; O]`, and i = 1, it should change it to `[O;L;R]`, but it doesn't. It seems to create the original list inside the new list and does this: `[R; R; O; O; L; O]`.

Help would be appreciated, I'm not sure where I'm going wrong!
Thanks

EDIT:
replacex is as follows:

```
let replacex ls i x = firstx ls (i-1) @ [x] @ lastx ls ((length ls)-i);;
```

And it's dependant functions are:

```
let rec firstx ls i = 
  match ls with
  | [] -> []
  | x::xs -> if i <> 1 then x::firstx xs (i-1) else [x];;

let rec reverse ls = 
 match ls with
  |[] -> []
  | x::xs -> reverse xs @ [x];;

let lastx ls i = reverse (firstx (reverse ls) i);;

let rec length ls = 
  match ls with
  | [] -> 0
  | x::xs -> 1+length xs;;

let rec getn ls i = match ls with
  | [] -> raise (Failure "empty list")
  | first::rest -> 
    if i = 0 then first 
    else getn rest (i-1);;
```

Comment: you should expose `replacex` definition to us

Comment: also where is `getn`

Comment: ..I knew I'd missed one! Added now.

Comment: Are you sure your `replacex` is correct? I tried `replacex [R;L;O]` I get `[R;L;O;R;L;O]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact, `replacex` function doesn't work correctly if you're trying to replace second element of the list. This leads to the call to `firstx` with second argument equal to `0`. And your implementation of `firstx` returns a full list in that case. You should either fix indices in, or rethink what is first zero elements.